# detectron2をオリジナルのデータで骨格検出でエラー：ValueError: expected sequence of length 19 at dim 1 (got 0)

Tags: python, opencv

detectron2を使用してカスタムデータの骨格検出を行いたいんですが、ValueError: expected sequence of length 19 at dim 1 (got 0)というエラーが出てしまいます。
使用しているデータセットには、杖を左で持った人と右で持った人が含まれており、どちらも"person"という同一のクラスを使用しています。右手で持っている人は右手首と杖の先端をつなげています。
使用しているキーポイントはこのような感じです

```
keypoint_names = ['nose', 'left_eye', 'right_eye', 'left_ear', 'right_ear', 'left_shoulder', 'right_shoulder', 'left_elbow', 'right_elbow', 'left_wrist', 'right_wrist', 'left_hip', 'right_hip', 'left_knee', 'right_knee', 'left_ankle','right_ankle', 'left_whitecane', 'right_whitecane']
```

接続関係はこうなっています

```
`keypoint_connection_rules = [('nose','left_eye',(50,0,0)),('nose','right_eye',(0,50,0)),('left_eye','left_ear',(0,0,50)),('right_eye','right_ear',(100,0,0)),('left_elbow','left_wrist',(0,100,0)),('right_elbow','right_wrist',(0,0,100)),
                         ('left_shoulder','left_elbow',(150,0,0)),('right_shoulder','right_elbow',(0,150,0)),('left_shoulder','left_hip',(0,0,150)),('right_shoulder','right_hip',(200,0,0)),('right_knee','right_hip',(0,200,0)),('left_knee','left_hip',(0,0,200)),
                         ('right_knee','right_ankle',(255,0,0)),('left_knee','left_ankle',(0,255,0)),('left_wrist','left_whitecane',(0,0,0)),('right_wrist','right_whitecane',(255,255,255))]`
```

初めての質問なので、わかりにくい部分があったら指摘していただきたいです。